# DelaunayMesh error : EmptyRegion

Tags: regions, mesh

What is wrong with the following list of points?

When I apply `DelaunayMesh[listPoints]` I get the error `A Delaunay tetrahedralization could not be found from the points...`

[image]

> EmptyRegion[3]

```
listPoints={{-1.35285, -1.80658, -1.80658}, {-1.97206, -4.34245, -4.34245}, {-1.31507, -4.01714, -4.01714}, {-0.388518, -0.407806, -0.407806}, {0.00449675, -0.533106, -0.533106}, {-1.82348, -2.77527, -2.77527}, {-1.19135, -1.09881, -1.09881}, {-2.07456, -3.55384, -3.55384}, {-0.259833, -0.785786, -0.785786}, {-0.681684, -0.839086, -0.839086}, {-0.502228, 0.0294242,   0.0294242}, {-1.43329, -3.86334, -3.86334}, {0.706892, -1.27352, -1.27352}, {-1.34993, -1.92591, -1.92591}, {-0.482381, -3.54387, -3.54387}, {-0.465172, -2.07591, -2.07591}, {-0.2935, -0.288653, -0.288653}, {-2.3759, -4.50828, -4.50828}, {0.4583, -3.02866, -3.02866}, {-2.32126, -4.56995, -4.56995}, {-1.25847, -1.3201, -1.3201}, {0.525251, -2.21353, -2.21353}, {-1.22322, -3.2869, -3.2869}, {0.0178493, -0.300984, -0.300984}, {-0.585227, -0.858825, -0.858825}, {-1.76939, -3.07957, -3.07957}, {1.2089, -2.43319, -2.43319}, {-0.49375, -0.18679, -0.18679}, {-0.581589, 0.290147,   0.290147}, {0.12325, -0.0679573, -0.0679573}, {-0.0274165, -2.36766, -2.36766}, {-0.725031, 0.59004,   0.59004}, {-0.963317, -0.182826, -0.182826}, {-0.369459, -2.45642, -2.45642}, {0.902533, -1.67231, -1.67231}, {-1.46413, -2.08622, -2.08622}, {-0.12143, -1.75514, -1.75514}, {-1.10789, -0.243582, -0.243582}, {-0.00483941, 0.0845077, 0.0845077}, {-0.130261, -3.37097, -3.37097}, {-1.45797, -1.48907, -1.48907}, {-0.505809, -2.40361, -2.40361}, {-0.124939, -2.48289, -2.48289}, {-1.75849, -3.33945, -3.33945}, {0.0316173, 0.154727,   0.154727}, {-0.118679, -3.10383, -3.10383}, {-1.00786, -1.28466, -1.28466}, {-1.47946, -2.19508, -2.19508}, {-0.0476823, -0.560066, -0.560066}, {-0.466555, -0.241466, -0.241466}}
```

Comment: Apparently, the points lie all in the same affine plane. That's why TetGen cannot mesh it (TetGen is for meshing volumes, only). And `DelaunayMesh` cannot mesh surfaces in 3-space. You may search this site for $\alpha$-shapes; there must be around some implementation  here.

Comment: Yes, ListPlot3D[listPoints] shows that

Answer (score 5):

Since the point cloud is planar, you can project to a plane, mesh there and embedd the resulting mesh back to 3-space. I use `Eigensystem` to find basis vectors to the best fitting hyperplane. In the following `A`

```
(* the two rows of A form a best-fitting orthonormal basis of the hyperplane in which the points lie*)
A = Eigensystem[listPoints\[Transpose].listPoints][[2, 1 ;; 2]];
p = Mean[listPoints];
n = Length[listPoints];
(* projecting to plane and meshing there*)
R = DelaunayMesh[(listPoints - ConstantArray[p, n]).Transpose[A]];
(* taking the resulting mesh and embedding it back into 3-space*)
M = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R].A + ConstantArray[p, n], MeshCells[R, 2]];

Show[M, Graphics3D[Sphere[listPoints, 0.05]], Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a bit what the code does?

Comment: @apt45 I added some comments within the code.